# Socket timeout not working

Tags: android, sockets, timeout

I have a TCP Socket running on a C# machine. I need to connect that server socket from Android via Server IP and port as below:

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIp);
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);
socket.setSoTimeout(10*1000);
```

If c# machine doesn't have socket running on Android it hangs on:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);
```

I need to implement 5 seconds as timeout like if it doesn't find server socket on this ip it could simply timeout.

Thoughts please..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May this help you:

**Create the socket with the no parameters constructor like this:**

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
```

**Then use**

```
socket.connect(remoteAddress, timeout);
```

**Another Way:**

```
Socket socket= new Socket();   
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostip,port_num),connection_time_out);
```

Comment: Socket socket= new Socket();   
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostip,port_num),connection_time_out); worked for me perfectly. Thanks Bhavin

Answer (score 1):

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIp);
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(serverAddr, timeout);
```

Comment: java.net.Socket doesn't contain such constructor: new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort, timeout). Any further help please?