# (Android) Socket connection to *offline* server takes too long to throw exception

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception, error-handling

I'm building an android app that connects with sockets to 3 Java servers.

Now, I'm trying to make it work, as long as at least 1 server is online, so what I do is check if the connection is ok and proceed, or if it throws an exception (meaning that the server is offline/does not respond etc.) I give the data for that server to the other availables.

With my Java dummy client, this works fine. The offline socket throws an exception and I can catch it and proceed with the rest of the process.

However, the Android client, keeps trying to connect to the offline sockets, for almost 5 minutes before finally throwing the exception and continuing.

I searched SO and the posts I found said it is a bug with the emulator, but testing on my actual device still takes 5 minutes to throw the exception.

Is there a fix or workaround for this? I need the client to stop waiting if more than 30 seconds have passed and no connection has been made.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should try to set the socket timeout http://stackoverflow.com/a/30392054/2442831

Comment: @Lino I tried it but it does not seem to be working... Just to be sure, is this the right way to do it?

`Socket s1 = new Socket(IP, PORT);
s1.setSoTimeout(3500);`

(IP and PORT are defined above and are fine). The code does not time out after 3.5 seconds even if the server is not running. It only throws a timeout after 3-5 minutes. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Found the solution! It's all here in this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780904/socket-timeout-not-working)

It is a workaround for the `.setSoTimeout()` that seems to not work.

thanks for the help guys!